# Create one big UML diagram from source with doxygen

Tags: java, uml, doxygen

I am using Doxygen with Dot in order to create an UML diagram of a Java project.
When I run Doxygen it creates a lot of .png uml files of the specifiy classes but **not** one "big" UML diagramm where all classes + member functions etc. are shown.

Is it possible to generate this? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 6):

To have one big diagram for all classes, you need in your **Doxyfile** enable`GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY` and `HAVE_DOT`.

```
# If you set the HAVE_DOT tag to YES then doxygen will assume the dot tool is 
# available from the path. This tool is part of Graphviz, a graph visualization 
# toolkit from AT&T and Lucent Bell Labs. The other options in this section 
# have no effect if this option is set to NO (the default)

HAVE_DOT               = YES

# If the GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY and HAVE_DOT tags are set to YES then doxygen 
# will generate a graphical hierarchy of all classes instead of a textual one.

GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
```

additionally, there is also

```
# If the UML_LOOK tag is set to YES doxygen will generate inheritance and 
# collaboration diagrams in a style similar to the OMG's Unified Modeling 
# Language.

UML_LOOK               = YES
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for collaboration diagrams as well? Cc: @albert

Comment: As far as I know there are no special commands for this for collaboration diagrams, but what would you (@user5534993) like to see?

Comment: I would like to see a combination of all collaboration diagrams. But without duplication of nodes. This will in general result in a diagram of disconnected graphs. How can this be achieved @albert? Possibly with additional tools?

Comment: @albert I don't think it is possible with plain doxygen. I have written [some scripts](https://github.com/dhebbeker/doxygen_collaboration_graph_combiner) in order to achieve that.